# Re-enable Bluez advertising after connection, through d-bus interface

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I have a BLE Gatt server, which is setup using the d-bus bluez interface (version 5.54).

Advertising is working using `org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1` and can be viewed using a BLE scanner Android app.

Making a connection to the server stops the device from advertising, and it is no longer visible on a BLE scanner.
Disconnecting doesn't start advertising again.

I've seen the same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236749/continue-advertising-after-connection-bluez), with a solution using `hcitool` commands.

Is there a way to re-enable advertising using the d-bus interface only?

Comment: well, did you try the RegisterAdvertisement and UnregisterAdvertisement methods?

Comment: Yes, I have tried re-calling RegisterAdvertisement which returns `org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists`. Unregistering then registering doesn't start advertising again. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: That's odd, because that is exactly how I am doing it. See https://github.com/weliem/bluez_inc/blob/main/binc/adapter.c#L963